# Function that copies a 3d array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, memcpy

Hi I stumbled upon a question in my textbook that states: 'Write a function that makes a copy of the contents of a 3D array of integers. The function should support any 3D array size.'

After discussing it with my lecturer he specified that the prototype of the function should look something similar to this (this is 2D, I need 3D).

```
int sum2d(int rows, int cols, int ar[rows][cols]);
```

Now how I currently coded it is by making everything in the main function and it works like it should, i.e copies all contents etc.

```
 int main()
    {
        int x,y,z;
        printf("Enter x value.\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Enter y value.\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        printf("Enter z value.\n");
        scanf("%d", &z);

        int *arrx = malloc(x * sizeof(*arrx));
        int *arry = malloc(y * sizeof(*arry));
        int *arrz = malloc(z * sizeof(*arrz));



        printf("The size of the array is %d.\n", x*y*z);
        /* 3D array declaration*/
        int disp[x][y][z];
        int cpydisp[x][y][z];


        /*Counter variables for the loop*/
        int i, j, k;
        for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
            for(j=0;j<y;j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                    printf("Enter value for disp[%d][%d][%d]:", i, j, k);
                    scanf("%d", &disp[i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }

        memcpy(cpydisp,disp, sizeof(disp));

        //Displaying array elements
        printf("Three Dimensional array elements:\n");
        for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
            for(j=0;j<y;j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                    printf("%d ", cpydisp[i][j][k]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

However this is not correct since I need to implement a function just for copying and I came up with this. Create a function called `void array_copy` which practically copies the contents of the array `disp` to another array `cpydisp` by  memcpy. The function `array_copy` is then called in the main however this is not working.

```
       int i, j, k;
        int x,y,z;
        int disp[x][y][z];
        int cpydisp[x][y][z];


void array_copy() {

        memcpy(cpydisp, disp, sizeof(disp));

    //Displaying array elements
        printf("Three Dimensional array elements:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                    printf("%d ", cpydisp[i][j][k]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("Enter x value.\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Enter y value.\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        printf("Enter z value.\n");
        scanf("%d", &z);

        //int *arrx = malloc(x * sizeof(*arrx));
        //int *arry = malloc(y * sizeof(*arry));
        //int *arrz = malloc(z * sizeof(*arrz));



        printf("The size of the array is %d.\n", x*y*z);
        /* 3D array declaration*/

        /*Counter variables for the loop*/
        int i, j, k;
        for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
            for(j=0;j<y;j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                    printf("Enter value for disp[%d][%d][%d]:", i, j, k);
                    scanf("%d", &disp[i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }

        array_copy();

    }
```

Any thoughts please on how I can get it fixed, since I can't seem to understand what's wrong with it when it clearly can take any size by the user imputing the size he wants prior to having anything started.

Thanks in Advance

Edit:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int x,y,z;
int i, j, k;

void user_input(){

    printf("Enter x value.\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter y value.\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Enter z value.\n");
    scanf("%d", &z);
}


void array_copy() {

    int disp[x][y][z];
    int cpydisp[x][y][z];

    memcpy(cpydisp, disp, sizeof(disp));
    //Displaying array elements
    printf("Three Dimensional array elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                printf("%d ", cpydisp[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    user_input();
    int disp[x][y][z];
    int cpydisp[x][y][z];

    printf("The size of the array is %d.\n", x*y*z);
    /* 3D array declaration*/

    /*Counter variables for the loop*/
    for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<y;j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                printf("Enter value for disp[%d][%d][%d]:", i, j, k);
                scanf("%d", &disp[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }

    array_copy();

}
```

I have retried it this way now something is being outputted rather than the second attempt however the output is just random numbers. i.e:

```
Enter x value.
1

Enter y value.
2

Enter z value.
3

The size of the array is 6.

Enter value for disp[0][0][0]:1
1
Enter value for disp[0][0][1]:2
2
Enter value for disp[0][0][2]:3
3
Enter value for disp[0][1][0]:4
4
Enter value for disp[0][1][1]:5
5
Enter value for disp[0][1][2]:6
6
Three Dimensional array elements:
797168 0 6421264
0 3 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The correct output should be `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Thanks again

Comment: You forget to pass the arrays (and their dimensions) as arguments to the function. Inside the `array_copy` function the variables `disp` and `cpydisp` are local *inside that function only*. Same with the *uninitialized* variable `x`, `y` and `z`.

Comment: And *why* do you have to "implement a function just for copying"? What's the reason for that? What problem is that supposed to solve that plain `memcpy` can't already solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I'm sorry I lost you, I took out the x, y and z as well as i,j,k and disp and cpydisp out however now it's giving me another type of error (I edited the code). With regards to what's the reason for it I guess to train us more than anything.

Comment: What are the `arrx` etc... for? you allocate memory for them and then do nothing with them - not even `free`ing the memory

Comment: of course not, not whilst you're using uninitialised variables to define the size of your global arrays. Plus you've ignored what your lecturer told you

Comment: Sorry however I don't understand what you mean, I really new to C and this is the first time I'm playing around with multiple functions ... I would appreciate if anyone can help me out on what actually needs to be done.

Comment: What about `cpy3d(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, int dst[x][y][z], int src[x][y][z]) { memcpy(dst, src, x*y*z * sizeof (int)); }`

Comment: Regarding your edit... you can't program by trial & error. There's no guessing, you need to know what each line you are writing actually does...

Comment: What I mean, is that your function is `void array_copy()` but your lecturer said it should look similar to `int sum2d(int rows, int cols, int ar[rows][cols])`

Comment: @ChrisTurner Oh I see I am trying the one that lundin suggested below however for some reason the output isn't stil correct.

Comment: dude_98 `int disp[x][y][z]; int cpydisp[x][y][z]; memcpy(cpydisp, disp, sizeof(disp));` --> The array `disp` elements are not initialized nor assigned.  Then code copies this unspecified data to `cpydisp`.  Why do you want a copy of junk?

Comment: @chux arent they initialized through the user input a few lines before?

Comment: dude_98 There are no "few lines before" `int disp[x][y][z];` in `void array_copy() {

    int disp[x][y][z]; ...`.  array_copy's `disp` is not initialized based on other code in other functions either.  main's `disp` is a different object than array_copy's `disp`.

Comment: @chux oh no i understand what you mean sorry ... how can I initialize it as a global variable then since C doesn't support this?

Comment: @dude_98 A global is not the the best approach.  Trying to _initialize_ a VLA is not allowed with C's concept of _initialize_: given a value at declaration.  See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135323/2410359)

Comment: C don't have any 2D or 3D arrays. It just have arrays (and they are unidimensionals). But it can have arrays of any type, including arrays of arrays of `int`, or arrays of arrays of arrays of `double`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have an actual 3D array, the function is simply:

```
memcpy( dst, src, sizeof(int[x][y][z]) );
```

If you want to write a less efficient version yourself, for learning purposes, then it goes like this:

```
void copy (size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, int dst[x][y][z], int src[x][y][z])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
    for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
      for(size_t k=0; k<z; k++)
        dst[i][j][k] = src[i][j][k];
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you used variable-length arrays (VLA) but declared them at file scope ("global"), which isn't allowed. VLA must be declared at local scope, and the array bounds must be set to valid values before the VLA declaration.

The above code doesn't care how the 3D array is allocated, but leaves that to the caller.

Comment: thanks for your reply I'll try it out. in this case how would you be able to print the elements? In my first attempt they print out by simply inserting the print statement in the last loop. Also when I call the function in the main, do I just simply do something along the lines of: `copy (x, y, z, cpydisp[x][y][z], disp[x][y][z])` Once again thanks for your help

Comment: @dude_98 Printing is as simple as `printf("%d ", arr[i][j][k]);` The function should be called as `copy(x, y, z, cpydisp, disp);`. Obviously, you need to initialize x, y and z to known values _before declaring the arrays_, or the compiler won't know what to do.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the way you suggested and trying it out however the output when I insert 1-6 like above six `0`s instead are being printed out instead of 1-6. P.S x,y,z are being initialized before it's being called i.e. from the user than it is called.

Comment: Typo has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> Write a function that makes a copy of the contents of a 3D array of integers. The function should support any 3D array size
>
> Something like
>
> `int sum2d(int rows, int cols, int ar[rows][cols]);`

OP's approach of using a global [variable-length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) fails as VLAs are  not allowed at file scope.

VLAs cannot be *initialized* (given a value at declaration).  However, their elements can be *assigned* at run-time.

---

With a VLA `d[x][y][z]` (available in C99 and optionally in C11), it is easy with `memcpy()`.
*Within a function*, use size: `sizeof d[0] * x`.

```
memcpy(d, src, sizeof d[0] * x);
```

Implementation notes:

`s, d` are pointers.

`size_t` is some unsigned type that is the right width for handling size and array indexes.  `int` may be too narrow.

With `int d[x][y][z]` as a parameter, the dimensional info `x` is lost.
`x` here  may be used by the compiler for select optimizations and checks, but code sees `d` as type `int (*)[y][z]`.

```
#include <stddef.h>

void copy3d(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, int d[x][y][z], int src[x][y][z]) {
  printf("s[%zu][%zu][%zu]\nSizes: d:%zu, d[]:%zu, d[][]:%zu, d[][][]:%zu\n\n",
      x, y, z, sizeof d, sizeof d[0], sizeof d[0][0], sizeof d[0][0][0]);
  // 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'src' returns 
  //     size of 'int (*)[(sizetype)(y)][(sizetype)(z)]
  memcpy(d, src, sizeof d[0] * x);
}
```

Sample usage

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  size_t x = (unsigned) rand() % 4 + 1;
  size_t y = (unsigned) rand() % 4 + 1;
  size_t z = (unsigned) rand() % 4 + 1;
  int src[x][y][z];
  int i = 0;

  for (size_t xi = 0; xi < x; xi++) {
    for (size_t yi = 0; yi < y; yi++) {
      for (size_t zi = 0; zi < z; zi++) {
        src[xi][yi][zi] = ++i;
      }
    }
  }

  int dest[x][y][z];
  // Call with two 3D: dest, and src, along with dimension info.
  copy3d(x, y, z, dest, src);

  for (size_t xi = 0; xi < x; xi++) {
    printf("{");
    for (size_t yi = 0; yi < y; yi++) {
      printf("{");
      for (size_t zi = 0; zi < z; zi++) {
        printf("%2d ", dest[xi][yi][zi]);
      }
      printf("}, ");
    }
    printf("}\n");
  }
}
```

Output

```
s[2][4][3]
Sizes: d:8, d[]:48, d[][]:12, d[][][]:4

{{ 1  2  3 }, { 4  5  6 }, { 7  8  9 }, {10 11 12 }, }
{{13 14 15 }, {16 17 18 }, {19 20 21 }, {22 23 24 }, }
```